# How to plot two-columns line graph on certain values of one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, linegraph

I have data frame with three columns : AgeCAT , DisCAT , counts .my DisCAT has 18 rows with string values . I want to plot a line graph for 5 of those values , have my 'AgeCAT' as x axis and 'counts' as y axis. I , however , couldn't find a solution to get those certain categories. 
I appreciate any help . 
here is what I have but it plots all data , I would like to get only 5 lines for 5 certain DisCAT data

```
#for plot only
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mplcm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

DisByAge=ERUse_new.groupby(['DisCAT','AgeCAT']).size().reset_index(name=
'counts')
DisByAge

#multiple line plot

DisByAge.pivot(index='AgeCAT',columns='DisCAT',values='counts').plot(
kind='line', figsize=(8,8))
```

Comment: Try something like `DisByAge=DisByAge[DisByAge.DisCAT.isin(['foo','bar', 'boz'])]` before plotting, that should filter accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot , It actually worked